# Multiple Favorites Stored In Database For Each User

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to set up a favorites table properly for a system where the favorited user's id is added to the table when the "add to favorites" button is clicked.

If each user only ever had 1 favorite it would be simple, but since each user would have multiple favorites I can't figure out how to make that work.

I have a USERS table with columns for User_ID, Username, Email Address, Password. I'd like to be able to add another user as a "Favorite" and be able to go to "My Favorites" page where they show up as a list.

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a table, we'll call `User_Favorites`, with columns `User_ID` and `Favored_User`.
The two fields together would be the PK for the table and each, separately,  would be a FK back to `Users`.

This allows you to have a user that 'favorited' every other user in the system

Answer (score 0):

Create another table, as a junction table. Many users have many bookmarks

```
Surrogate Key|UserWithBookmarkID(USER_ID)|UserThatIsBookmarkID(USER_ID)
```